# How to save the answers to this questionnaire on Heroku?

Tags: php, database, facebook, heroku

I made this [questionnaire](https://afternoon-beach-5439.herokuapp.com/) on Heroku using Javascript. As you can see it's very rudimentary at the moment lol.

The questionnaire only has 3 questions. When the user clicks "submit" I would like to store their answers on Heroku. Then my program can display the results for how many people answered "yes" and "no" for each of those questions.

How can I store these answers to a database on Heroku? I guess I'll have to use PHP to accomplish this?

Comment: You have so many options ... what database are you looking at ???

Comment: Heroku offers a free Postgres DB for all sites - only has 5 MB of storage for the free level ... $15/month for 20 GB (I think it's 20 GB  but am not 100% on that as I'm writing this from memory, such that it is!). In terms of server-side languages, you can use PHP, Ruby/Rails, Java, Scala, Clojure ... you get the idea! Rails makes it pretty dang easy to hook up to and use a Heroku DB. Check out their docs. Good info there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of a few things.

1. Use some sort of synchronization service like firebase.
2. Use some other survey service (like google docs) or make api calls to it from your app.
3. Put a database on your app and write a backend for your javascript to return survey results to.

   I personally would use firebase because it won't require you to write a backend and has a super simple api.